# All bear Locations in BOTW

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

After looking on YouTube, I discovered bears are tamable in Breath of the Wild. 
Does anyone know any locations?

Comment: If you have photographed one, doesn't the Hyrule Compendium tell you where they can be found? It might not be precise but it's a start.

Comment: @Kozaky the [Hyrule Compendium](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Hyrule_Compendium) just gives you a region (which can be really big), after that you would have to wander around with the sheikah slate with the bear targeted listening for the beeps.

Comment: Keep in mind that "tamable" is a relative term (unless things have changed in updates/DLCs since I finished the game.)  You can mount and ride various wild animals, but you can't keep them in stables.  After you get off, it will run away.

Answer (score 17):

There are two species of bear in BOTW, The Honeyvore Bear found in Tabantha Frontier and Akkala Highlands and the Grizzlemaw Bear found in Hebra Mountains
and Gerudo Highlands. The bears spawn in the locations below (Light Blue is Grizzlemaw and Purple is Honeyvore):

[image: Bear Spawns]

You can check out the [full interactive map here](https://mrcheeze.github.io/botw-object-map/) if you want to zoom in more detailed on the map, but this should be good enough to get you started. Just head to the locations on the map and change your Sheikah sensor to target the bear you are looking for.